# Wiener filter output doesn't look good enough

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, filtering, wiener-filter

I have an image, I add some noise to it and try to denoise it using wiener filter:

[image]

Which in case of additive white noise and no blurring simplifies to:

[image]

Here is my code according to above formula, however, there is almost no difference with the input image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img=cv2.imread('Images/P3.jpg',0)
freq2 = np.fft.fft2(img)
mean = 0
var = 100
sigma = var**0.5
gauss = np.random.normal(mean,sigma,np.shape(img))
courrupted=img+gauss
freq2h = np.fft.fft2(gauss)
courrupted[courrupted<0]=0
courrupted[courrupted>255]=255
courrupted=courrupted.astype(np.uint8)

crfre=np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(courrupted))
sf=np.abs(crfre)**2

wiener=sf/(sf+(100))
F_hat = crfre*wiener
f_hat = np.fft.ifft2( (F_hat))
restored = abs(f_hat)
normalizedImg=np.ones(img.shape)
normalizedImg = cv2.normalize(restored,  normalizedImg, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

cv2.imwrite('output.jpg',normalizedImg)
cv2.imwrite('input.jpg',courrupted)
```

This is ground truth image:

[image]

This is input:

[image]

And this is output:

[image]

Comment: When asking a question related to code, it is **always** necessary to add a tag for the language being used. This not only helps get the question in front of people that might be able to answer it more quickly, but it helps future site users find it when searching. Please [edit] to add that tag. Also, your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Why are you adding gauss to your input twice? You have `courrupted=img+gauss` followed by `courrupted=courrupted+gauss`.  Why are you taking 10 time the log of the magnitude?  You should just use the magnitude of the Fourier transform of the signal. Have you viewed your noisy image?  Does it look like it has a reasonable amount of noise?

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks, I edit that, however, still no big improve, by the way I added ground truth image to see noise more clearly!

Comment: Don’t use `np.fft.fftshift` (or at least shift back before inverse transforming). Also don’t use `abs` of the inverse transform, it should be real-valued, the imaginary part is 0 (except for rounding errors), so take the real part. — none of this fixes your issue, but will improve your code.

Comment: The `sf/(sf+(100))` part might assume a different normalization of your Fourier transform. Try increasing the constant by adding a zero at the time, as long as the output improves.

Comment: This scene is heavily textured, so separating noise from signal is elusive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me in Python/OpenCV/Numpy. As @Cris Luengo suggested, you need to test various values for the noise value, because the value you need may not be exactly your Gaussian variance input value.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('pandas_noisy.jpg',0)

# take dft
dft = np.fft.fft2(img)

# get power spectral density of dft = square of magnitude
# where abs of complex number is the magnitude
pspec = (np.abs(dft))**2
print(np.amin(pspec))
print(np.amax(pspec))

# estimate noise power spectral density
# try different values to achieve compromise between noise reduction and softening/blurring
#noise = 100000000
#noise = 500000000
#noise = 1000000000
noise = 5000000000

# do wiener filtering
wiener = pspec/(pspec+noise)
wiener = wiener*dft

# do dft to restore
restored = np.fft.ifft2(wiener)

# take real() component (or do abs())
restored = np.real(restored)
print(np.amin(restored))
print(np.amax(restored))

# clip and convert to uint8
restored = restored.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# save results
#cv2.imwrite('pandas_noisy_restored_100000000.jpg',restored)
#cv2.imwrite('pandas_noisy_restored_500000000.jpg',restored)
#cv2.imwrite('pandas_noisy_restored_1000000000.jpg',restored)
cv2.imwrite('pandas_noisy_restored_5000000000.jpg',restored)

# display results
cv2.imshow("input", img)
cv2.imshow("restored", restored)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Restored Result for Noise=100000000:

[image]

Restored Result for Noise=500000000:

[image]

Restored Result for Noise=1000000000:

[image]

Restored Result for Noise=5000000000:

[image]

Comment: I figure noise power would be something like `640*480*100 = 30720000` (number of pixels times variance), but that doesn't seem to be anywhere near the value you needed to fill in. I've never been able to use a Wiener filter without manually tweaking the parameter to best effect. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: That was my experience also. I had to manually try different values to get a good result. I figured that there were other issues contributing to the change from an optimal value.